# Checkboxes value not visible in mozilla Firefox

Tags: html

I have these two checkboxes

```html
    <input type="checkbox" id="OP" name="calendario" value="Ore Personali" checked>
    <input type="checkbox" id="assenze" name="calendario" value="Assenze">
```

This is how i see them in Chrome: [image: chrome]

And this is in mozilla: [image: mozilla]

I read that there is this bug where the values in mozilla are not visible, but online i didnt find a solution. Can someone help me pls?

I tried add a label but it overlaps with the value and i cannot remove the values cause they are connected to a function in javascript

---

i appreciate your answer @lupz
But as i already tried before and as you suggest, for mozilla the problem is resolved but this is the result in chrome [image: chrome2]

---

This is the only function in JS where these 2 checkboxes are mention:

```js
$("input[name=calendario]:checked").each(function() {
  selections.push($(this).val());
});
var showEvent = false;
if (selections.indexOf("Ore Personali") >= 0 && event.nomeUtente == $("#nomeUtente").data('value')) showEvent = true;
if (selections.indexOf("Assenze") >= 0 && event.nomeUtente != $("#nomeUtente").data('value')) showEvent = true;
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="list-group has-actions">
  <div class="list-group-item" data-plugin="editlist">
    <div class="list-content">
      <input type="checkbox" id="OP" name="calendario" value="Ore Personali" checked>
      <label for="OP">Ore Personali</label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="list-group-item" data-plugin="editlist">
    <div class="list-content">
      <input type="checkbox" id="assenze" name="calendario" value="Assenze">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

**found the solution:**

i had in my css:

```
[type=checkbox]:after {
content: attr(value) !important; }
```

I just had to remove it. Didnt know it was there cause it's a template the code i'm using

Comment: Could you please share a reference/source for that bug?

Comment: I rembember read about that under an question here on stackoverflow, but it was like a month ago and dont remember unfortunatelly where exactly

Comment: Checkbox value attributes are not displayed normally. They shouldn't be visible in Chrome. Maybe you have some CSS or JavaScript which renders them (and also stops them being on the same line) which isn't working in Firefox. You didn't include that in the question though. You need to provide a [mcve].

Comment: okay sorry, i have update it

Comment: @nana — That code errors. Please provide a [mcve]. Not an out of context chunk of code that might be relevant. A real [mcve].

Comment: I always saw ppl doing like that, didnt know i had to add link or stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a special `label` tag that you can (and should) use to display actual labels for form elements. I think there is some additional "magic" going on in your project that shows those checkbox values directly. At least at my end, chrome and FF both don't show the checkbox values.

```html
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="OP" name="calendario" value="Ore Personali" checked>
  <label for="OP">Ore Personali</label>
</div>

<div>
  <input type="checkbox" id="assenze" name="calendario" value="Assenze">
  <label for="assenze">Assenze</label>
</div>
```

Check out https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Input/checkbox for the details.

Comment: I update the result with your suggestion, unfortunately, for once, i would love not to have "magic" in my code hahaha

Comment: @nana this is issue with your code in js. browsers do not display their value as text by default

Comment: Unfortunately you did not provide enough info. By "magic" I refer to those unknown bits. There are preprocessors, virtual dom frameworks, CSS tricks and more... something is creating labels auto-magically from the values in chrome. Maybe you can use the inspector of your browsers debugging tools to get a glimpse on where those labels are comming from.

Comment: Already tried seeing something from the inspector but i'm a noob and havent's found anything. I know by magic u meant that but as i said in my update question i tried removing avery css stuff and didnt change anything. For other try i dont know how to check so i'm kinda lost

Comment: The "magic" is some pseudo element selector in your CSS code, something like `input[type=checkbox]::after{content: attr(value);}` which you should remove.

Comment: Oh okay, @connexo u actually found my solution

Comment: should i update the answer or you want to post it so i can vote it?

Comment: I think you can just delete your question. Without knowing which exact template comes with this, this question won't be any useful for future visitors.